# VNC too many authentication failures error - Fail2ban

Tags: debian, vnc, fail2ban

On a Debian 11 server with Xtightvnc, I am getting a lot of "too many authentication failures" messages.
I would like to put fail2ban to block unauthorized users who try to login into my server via VNC. But I can't find a rule that works.
The rules I find are old and don't work with the log.

```
14/10/21 20:37:43 Got connection from client 209.141.49.123
14/10/21 20:37:43 Using protocol version 3.3
14/10/21 20:37:43 Too many authentication failures - client rejected
14/10/21 20:37:43 Client 209.141.49.123 gone
14/10/21 20:37:43 Statistics:
14/10/21 20:37:43   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
```

I'm using iptables to release only my access ip, but I don't want this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this VNC logging has a not really appropriate log-format for fail2ban - the message with failure doesn't contain IP address and entries with IP and failed attempt don't contain some identifier to be able to group them by this ID.

Basically fail2ban can handle such multi-line logs (containing IP in one line and failure in another line) with two processing methods:

- jail/filter with `maxlines` >= 2 scrolling over log with a messages window containing more than 1 message;
- new multi-line processing using `<F-MLFID>...</F-MLFID>` tags to capture session-related ID in every line in order to consider 2 messages are from the same client.

Both methods are not really suitable here.

Shortly you cannot distinguish the legitimate attempt from failed attempts if they occur simultaneously, for example:

```
Got connection from client 192.0.2.111
Got connection from client 192.0.2.222
Too many authentication failures - client rejected
Client successfully connected ~artificial log-entry (I don't know ~
```

Here we see 2 clients got connected, but one fails and another is successful. Which one was successful and which doesn't?

There is still one log-entry (with IP and `gone`) implictely after rejected message, so if you would say that it is improbable that a client is gone directly after successful connection, you can say we'll consider nearby messages with `client rejected` and `gone` as messages from same client (it's a bit "dangerous", especially if there are no further messages between success at some point and gone later, but...).

Then one could use following configuration:

```
# increasing the value of `maxlines` would make that the filter works more precise (can consider failures also in case of some flood in log between `client rejected` and `gone`),
# but it would make it more unsafe at the same time (because it can cause false positives on `gone` messages from legitimate clients occurring after `client rejected` logged from evildoers):

maxlines = 2

failregex = ^\s*Too many authentication failures - client rejected<SKIPLINES>\s*Client <ADDR> gone
```

(replace `<ADDR>` with `<HOST>` if your fail2ban version is older than 0.10)

But anyway it would be better to fix it on VNC site - e. g. adding IP address directly in `client rejected` message or introducing some session-related ID identifying client unambiguously.